# Как симулировать нажатие клавиш и передвижение мыши?

Tags: python

Вроде можно через модуль win32api, а вот как? Есть ли гайды по этому поводу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все кароче разобрался `win32api.SetCursorPos([500,500])`

Answer (score 3):

Если надо написать простенький кликер,я бы посоветовал использовать Pyauto gui. Там можно сравнивать место нажатия мышки по изображению или так же прописывать координаты. Чтобы получить бОльший контроль над программой, то используйте Swapy (например если кликать нужно на всплывающие окна, которые не всегда появляются в одном и  том же месте)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите еще Open Source проект [dogtail](https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/) от Fedora. Правда, применяется он для тестирования GUI приложений.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, лучше вам пригодится PyQT4, вам нужно использовать [события и сигналы](http://wiki.python.su/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%92%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83PyQt4#A.2BBCEEPgQxBEsEQgQ4BE8_.2BBDg_.2BBEEEOAQzBD0EMAQ7BEs-), чтобы 'симулировать' нажатие клавиш и передвижение мыши. Посмотрите еще [Рисование](http://wiki.python.su/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%92%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83PyQt4#A.2BBCAEOARBBD4EMgQwBD0EOAQ1-).

Comment: а тут только внутри созданного мной приложения можно или ваще везде??? могу я например написать координаты, а она туда щелкнет мышкой

Comment: Только в приложении будет реагировать на события. Так везде думаю.